# Delphi: Disable TaskManager in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, taskmanager

I found [this code](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0103_2.htm) for disabling the task manager in Windows XP. It works :)

But does it work in Windows 7, too? The registry path is the same, I've checked this. But maybe there are some restrictions!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For us who do not remember XP very well: can you describe in what way the code "disables" the "task manager"? I just tried the code on W7 Home Premium, and I cannot see any change made by the code. And, really, it would be stupid if a single application could do this, even if it was running with raised privileges.

Comment: The code sets a registry key, which disables the button on the security dialog screen and the menu command on the taskbar's context menu. If you run taskmgr.exe directly, it displays a dialog box telling you that the administrator has disabled it. You can set it in either KHCU or HKLM. You don't need special privileges to disable it in HKCU, which also means you don't need special privileges to re-enable it, so it's not really all that remarkable a setting.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it does. If you call the task manager by Ctrl+Alt+Del then the dialog "disabled by administrator" also appears.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: So the code doesn't work on Windows 7? Isn't there this dialog?

Comment: @marco92w: In Windows 7 Home Premium, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del takes you to the Welcome screen, but instead of the user account icons, there are buttons for Lock Workstation, Change User, Log Out, Change Password, and Task Manager. The last one starts the Task Manager, as if you'd pressed Ctrl+Shift+Esc.

Comment: Converted from answer that was more of a comment.... I wouldn't approach this as a Delphi question. The code that you cited just modifies the registry. You can test this by hand using RegEdit to see if you can get the desired effect. If you find that you can run a .reg script through regedit and that works, but a Delphi program to do the same does not work, THEN it becomes a Delphi question. Right now, as I see it, you've got a "how do I disable the TaskManager by manipulating the registry" question.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas Rejbrand, I didn't know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the below keys have "readonly" access for standard users since Windows 2000 (See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742499.aspx)).

- HKLM\Software\Policies
- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
- HKCU\Software\Policies
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies

So your application needs to have administrative privileges in order to write to these keys.

Comment: Thank you. My question was if it works in Windows 7, too. So is it possible to change those keys in Windows 7 with administrative privileges, too? Or did they block access for those keys in Windows 7?

Comment: @marco92w: If the keys exist, I think they can be altered with admin privs. I will try this later tonight.

Comment: @marco92w - Yes, I did test with a quick app on W7 with the "DisableTaskMgr", if "run as administrator", TRegistry successfully writes the key and the value and task manager is effectively disabled.

Comment: But on Windows 7, programms seem to be firstly executed as a normal user without administrative privileges, right? This is a difference to Windows XP - and exactly what I wanted to know. :)

Comment: Yes, if UAC is enabled (which is the default state), even when an admin is logged on, the applications are ran in the context of a standard user, unless "run as administrator" is selected, or the application requires administrative privileges by means of a manifest for instance. In either case a dialog is shown before the app is ran, asking for affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works in Windows 7 too. I ran the program with raised privileges (Windows 7 Home Premium), and after that the Task Manager is no longer available.

But, as a sidenote, I have to say that the code

```
case YesNo of
  False:
    begin
      WriteInteger('DisableTaskMgr',1) ;
    end;
  True:
    begin
      WriteInteger('DisableTaskMgr',0) ;
    end;
end;
```

is rather horrible. First of all, there is no need at all for the `begin` and `end` parts, because the commands `WriteInteger...` are "one-liners". Secondly, why not just write the value of `not YesNo`?

One really should write the code as

```
WriteInteger('DisableTaskMgr', byte(not YesNo));
```

Isn't that much more readable and brief?

Comment: Thank you very very much, Andreas! What a great optimization! A 10-line code block made to a simple 1-liner ...